# how to deploy solution Package file in Sharepoint 2013?

Tags: asp.net, powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I Need to Deploy The Solution Package in SharePoint 2013.On Reading Some Articles I came to know to make a wsp of you Solution and than Deploy Using Managment Shell and Than Deploy it in Central Admin.

Will My Wsp File will work if Deployed in some one else Central Administrator.
Actually I need to host This Program In Clients SharePoint.

1)how to Deploy Windows Solution Package?
2)On Deploy My Wsp File In Central Admin Will User Able to see the things in Sharepoint Screen.

Comment: 1) Did you check this article: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262995(v=office.14).aspx#DeployFarmSolutions ?

2) After deploying the solution, you need to activate your features on desired site collecton/sites. After that, users will see libraries, custom actions or whatever else you are adding in the package.

Comment: http://jaxsharepoint.blogspot.in/2013/06/deploying-wsp-to-sharepoint-2013.html      I have done this which is shown in the above link and its working fine....Now If i give Solution file.....  .wsp File to the client to work on his sharepoint will it work.Its workin on My Sharepoint 2013 through Central Admin.

Comment: Yes, it should work on his SP2013 as well.